# How to hyphenate a string/text in a textarea using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hyphenation

I am not able to hyphenate strings using jQuery. It seems there is no library available. I tried [this link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryHyphenate) but failed. Please help if you know how to hyphenate a string in a textarea according to a textarea's width using a jQuery plugin.

Comment: use regular expression. I din't get your question do u want to hypened(`-`) all the text in textarea?? m i right?? please paste your code and desired output

Comment: Try something like this http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/downloads/list ?

Answer (score 4):

I think Hypher is what you're looking for:

https://github.com/bramstein/hypher

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016 there is another JavaScript library available that you could use: https://github.com/ytiurin/hyphen

Compared to Hypher, **hy-phen** is easier to include on your page, since it does not depend on Node.js or jQuery. You simply have to include the JavaScript file for the library and the pattern file for your desired language using a `<script>` tag.